# Invalid template file in Magento 2.3

Tags: magento2, template, docker

I have been reading the forum but I can't find any solution to solve my case.

I have a custom module where I'm getting the error:

> 1 exception(s): Exception #0
> (Magento\Framework\Exception\ValidatorException): Invalid template
> file: 'simulator.phtml' in module: '<module_name>' block's name:
> 'product.view.simulator'

My module works with Magento 2.2 but after upgrade to 2.3, it does not work. I use Mac & docker(Image:Alex Cheung/magento2:latest), no windows.
I think the problem is in the symlink which is not getting the right path.

File: `catalog_product_view.xml` (I have tried with the template set to <module_name>: simulator.phtml but it doesn't work)
I hace tried changing the module location:

> vendor//magento-2x/.. or app/code/...

but it now works

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns :xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
   <body>
       <referenceBlock name="product.info.addtocart">
          <block class="<vendor>\<module_name>\Block\Product\Simulator"
           name="product.view.simulator"
           as="product_simulator"
           template="simulator.phtml"/>
       </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Some ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Solution: The problem was solved enabling symlinks to the template(Advance->Developer in Magento admin panel), but I have read that it's dangerous :S

Comment: Are you sure you created the simulator.phtml in the right directory? I think you should post your full module directory/file tree

Comment: Path is right, it reachs at the right destination

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to update the **template** attribute to correct one with full module path like below

```
template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/simulator.phtml"
```

Hope this will help you.

Thanks

Comment: But simulator.phtml is my template file, it is not a Magento_Catalog file. Anyway it does not works

Comment: Magento_Catalog is just a place holder you need to use your module name like 
DigitalOrigin_Pmt::simulator.phtml

Comment: I tested this solution before but it continues failing

Comment: wath is the path of your simulator.phtml file like its under template directory or under sub directory please add path here

Comment: Template path: /view/frontend/templates/product/simulator.phtml

Comment: template="DigitalOrigin_Pmt::product/simulator.phtml" add this

Comment: [2019-03-04 11:38:15] main.CRITICAL: Invalid template file: '/var/www/html/vendor/composer/../pagamastarde/magento-2x/view/frontend/templates/product/simulator.phtml' in module: 'DigitalOrigin_Pmt' block's name: 'product.view.simulator' [] []

If I execute this command, I can see the file content: "cat /var/www/html/vendor/composer/../pagamastarde/magento-2x/view/frontend/templates/product/simulator.phtml".

The file has 777 permissions

Comment: OK change this file permission to 644

Comment: The problem was solved enabling symlinks to template, but I have read that it's dangerous :S

Answer (score 0):

**Template Path Given Like This**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns :xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
   <body>
       <referenceBlock name="product.info.addtocart">
          <block class="DigitalOrigin\Pmt\Block\Product\Simulator"
           name="product.view.simulator"
           as="product_simulator"
           template="Vendor_ModuleName::simulator.phtml"/>
       </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Comment: 1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\ValidatorException): Invalid template file: 'Vendor_ModuleName::simulator.phtml' in module: 'DigitalOrigin_Pmt' block's name: 'product.view.simulator'

Comment: template="DigitalOrigin_Pmt::simulator.phtml"  just change it

Comment: Using template="DigitalOrigin_Pmt::simulator.phtml" still fails. It's not the solution

Comment: Your template file location ?

Comment: Template path: /view/frontend/templates/product/simulator.phtml

Comment: template="DigitalOrigin_Pmt::product/simulator.phtml" try this

Comment: [2019-03-04 11:38:15] main.CRITICAL: Invalid template file: '/var/www/html/vendor/composer/../pagamastarde/magento-2x/view/frontend/templates/product/simulator.phtml' in module: 'DigitalOrigin_Pmt' block's name: 'product.view.simulator' [] []

If I execute this command, I can see the file content: "cat /var/www/html/vendor/composer/../pagamastarde/magento-2x/view/frontend/templates/product/simulator.phtml".

The file has 777 permissions

Comment: The problem was solved enabling symlinks to template, but I have read that it's dangerous :S

Answer (score 0):

Magento can not locate your template because you have the wrong path in your layout xml file.

```
template="Vendor_ModuleName::simulator.phtml"/>
```

If the path to your actual template file is:
DigitalOrigin/Pmt/view/frontend/templates/product/simulator.phtml

then it should be like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns :xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
   <body>
       <referenceBlock name="product.info.addtocart">
          <block class="DigitalOrigin\Pmt\Block\Product\Simulator"
           name="product.view.simulator"
           as="product_simulator"
           template="Vendor_ModuleName::product/simulator.phtml"/>
       </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

And please do change {Vendor_ModuleName} to your actual package name. Its just a placeholder above in the code snippet